# Перевод из Base36 в десятичное число

Tags: sql

Есть строка, 16 символов.
Как можно перевести в Base10?
Может есть готовая функция в MS SQL?
Нашел функцию для строки из 6 символов только, а вот как сделать на 16 не понимаю.

Comment: а вот [эту](https://dzone.com/articles/convert-number-any-base) функцию не пробовали использовать?

Comment: Пробовал. Выполняю так: SELECT dbo.f_convert_to_base10('000003GPD8OG3K84', 36) AS [decimal]


В итоге получаю ошибку: Ошибка арифметического переполнения для типа int, значение = 2176782336.000000.

Comment: Получается эта функция работает на длину строки не более 5